# reader priority using semaphores

Tags: c, synchronization, deadlock, semaphore

I am hitting a wall with a project I am working on and I was wondering if anyone can provide me with some help. I'll try to simplify my code so you aren't staring at 100+ lines of jibberish. I am pretty sure the only the first code block is relevant, the others are my system calls in sys.c for reference.

I am supposed to create a program to simulate a reader priority implementation of process synchronization using my own semaphores. When I run it I reach a deadlock whenever a reader gets to the critical section. I don't know what I did wrong.

An example output is:

Writer 0 wrote- 6

writer 1 wrote- 4

Writer 2 wrote- 2

Reader 0 read- 2

and then it freezes.

From what I can tell the Critcal Section semaphore is never getting released.

I believe the problem is with my program, and not with my semaphore and wait and signal opertaions, but I included them below for reference.

Thanks in advance.

My attempt so far is as follows:
I left out my initialization and memory mapping, this is the basic structure

Notes: 
RWwait and RWsignal are wrapper methods which successfully make systems calls to my semaphore operations.
csMutex is to control access to the critical section.
nrMutex is to control the queue of readers to the critical section
Both mutex values are originally 1.
*number is a pointer to number which both readers and writers have access to

```
int i;
//create writers
for(i=0; i < writers; i++){
    if (fork()==0){
        while(1){
            RWwait(csMutex);    //wait for the critical section and lock
            *number = rand() % 10;
            printf("Writer %d wrote- %d\n", i, *number);
            RWsignal(csMutex);//unlock critical section
        }
    }
}

int nr = 0;     //number of readers
//create readers
for(i=0; i < readers; i++){
    if (fork()==0){
            while(1){
            RWwait(nrMutex);
            nr++;

            if (nr == 1) 
                RWwait(csMutex);
            RWsignal(nrMutex);

            printf("Reader %d read- %d\n", i, *number);

            RWwait(nrMutex);
            nr--;
            if (nr == 0)
            RWsignal(csMutex);
                RWsignal(nrMutex);
        }
    }
}
```

THESE ARE MY SYSTEM CALLS AND STRUCTURES IN sys.c
AGAIN, JUST FOR REFERENCE

```
struct ProcQ {
    struct task_struct *ts;
    struct ProcQ *next;

};
```

and

```
struct RW_Sem {
    int value;
    char *type;
    //Front and back nodes for the queue
    struct ProcQ *front;
    struct ProcQ *back;
};
```

Wait Operation:

```
asmlinkage long sys_RW_wait(struct RW_Sem *sem){
spin_lock(&sem_lock);   //locks the program
sem->value -= 1;    //decrement value

if (sem->value < 0){            //insert into queue
    struct ProcQ *node; //create a new node for the queue
    node = (struct ProcQ*)kmalloc(sizeof(struct ProcQ), GFP_KERNEL);
    node->ts = current; //assign this process to task_struct
    node->next = NULL;  //assign the next node to null

    if(sem->front == NULL){ //if the process queue is empty
        sem->front = node;
        sem->back = node;
    }

    else{   //if the queue is NOT empty
        sem->back->next = node;
        sem->back = node;       
    }
    set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);  //sleep my child
    spin_unlock(&sem_lock);         //unlock
    schedule();
}

else{                   //queue bypass
    spin_unlock(&sem_lock);
}
return 0;
}
```

Signal Operation:

```
asmlinkage long sys_RW_signal(struct RW_Sem *sem){
spin_lock(&sem_lock);   //locks the program
sem->value += 1;        //increment value


if(sem->value <= 0){                     //wake up process, otherwise bypass
    struct ProcQ *dqProc;            //temporary node pointer for signaled process
    struct task_struct *wake;        //temp for task struct to wake
    dqProc = sem->front;

    if (dqProc != NULL) {          
        wake = dqProc->ts;
        if(sem->front==sem->back){      //if only item in queue
            sem->front = NULL;
            sem->back = NULL;   
        }

        else{
                sem->front = dqProc->next;
        }

        wake_up_process(wake);  //wake up!
        kfree(dqProc);                  //free that space
    }

}

spin_unlock(&sem_lock); //unlock
return 0;       //success!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say in your reader:

```
        nr++;

        if (nr == 1) 
            RWwait(csMutex);
```

Is a race condition.

Similarly I would not do:

```
        if (nr == 0)
        RWsignal(csMutex);
```

Comment: Without the first one, wouldn't it then be possible for the reader to access the critical section while a reader was already there?
The idea with these was that if this was the first reader nr==1 then it would wait for all writers to finish. Then writers could not access the CS until all readers have finished nr == 0.

Comment: Its a race condition because theoretically two readers could each execute nr ++ ; before either executes the line if ( nr == 0 )

Comment: ahhhh! You're right! Any ideas on how I could get around this? If I take those lines out then it would get rid of the race condition, but it would give readers and writers equal priority, no?

Comment: Priority is a whole nother matter.  If you want to let readers share a lock, you'll have to create an additional process safe mechanism for that.

Comment: Thats what the nrMutex was supposed to achieve.